# Search multiple fields MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, search, pdo

I have a database like this :

```
ID | Name | Model | Type
1  | Car  | 4     | C
2  | Bar  | 2     | B
3  | Car  | 4     | D
4  | Car  | 3     | D
```

And a form like this :

```
Name : 
Model : 
Type :
```

Now, I would like to search only the name, for example "Car" and it returns lines 1, 3, 4. (I left Model and Type empty)

If I search "Car" in Name and 4 in Model, it returns lines 1, 3. (I left Type empty)

And if I search "Car" in Name and "D" in Type, it returns line 3, 4 (I left Model empty)

Is it possible to do this in one query ?

This is what I had :

```
SELECT *
FROM items
WHERE (:name IS NOT NULL AND name = :name)
AND (:model IS NOT NULL AND model = :model)
AND (:type IS NOT NULL AND type = :type)
```

But it doesn't work.
I would like to fill only 2 on 3 fields and the the "WHERE" adapts and ignore the blank field.

**EDIT 1 :** It is a little hard to explain but I have a form. I want to have only one required field, the two others are optional but if I also fill the one other or two others fields, they act like a filter.

So the name field is required (in the form). If I fill only the name field, it will select only where name = :name.
If I fill name + model, it will select where name = :name AND model = :model.
and so on...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Use `OR` not `AND` for the additional parameters. `(:name IS NOT NULL AND name = :name)
OR (:model IS NOT NULL AND model = :model)`

Comment: You alternatively could make the `where` a variable and add only the values you need via conditionals and in the conditionals do the binding.

Comment: @chris85 Thank you Chris. The problem with OR is that if I search Car in Name and 4 in Model, even the line 4 (Car - 3) appears...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an alternative approach using PHP. You'll need to update the variables.

```
<?php
$query = 'SELECT *
FROM items
WHERE 1 = 1 ';
//below used for testing can be remove
//$_GET['name'] = 'test';
//$_GET['car'] = 'test2';
//$_GET['type'] = 'test3';
if(!empty($_GET['name'])) {
    $query .= ' and name = ? ';
    $params[] = $_GET['name'];
}
if(!empty($_GET['car'])) {
    $query .= ' and car = ? ';
    $params[] = $_GET['car'];
}
if(!empty($_GET['type'])) {
    $query .= ' and type = ? ';
    $params[] = $_GET['type'];
}
if(!empty($params)) {
    $dbh->prepare($query);
    $sth->execute($params);
    //fetch
} else {
    echo 'Missing Values';
}
```

The `1=1` is so you can append `and search field` for each field with a value otherwise you'd need to see if it'd already been set.

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind ! I just had to replace `$dbh->prepare($query);` with `$sth = $dbh->prepare($query);` in order to avoid a variable error. Thank you again !

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you mean by "blank", but assuming you mean `NULL`, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM items
WHERE (:name IS NULL OR name = :name) AND
      (:model IS NULL OR model = :model) AND
      (:type IS NULL OR type = :type);
```

That problem with this query is that it is very hard for MySQL to use indexes for it, because of the `or` conditions.  If you have a large amount of data, and want to use indexes, then you should construct the `where` clauses based on the parameters that actually have data.

Comment: It is a little hard to explain but I have a form. I want to have only one required field, the two others are optional but if I also fill the one other or two others fields, they act like a filter.